# Why django order_by is so slow in a manytomany query?

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, django-orm

I have a ManyToMany field. Like this:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    books = models.ManyToManyField ('book.Book', related_name='vtags', through=TagBook)

class Book (models.Model): 
    nump = models.IntegerField (default=0, db_index=True)
```

I have around 450,000 books, and for some tags, it related around 60,000 books. When I did a query like:

```
tag.books.order_by('nump')[1:11]
```

It gets extremely slow, like 3-4 minutes. 
But if I remove order_by, it run queries as normal.

The raw sql for the order_by version looks like this:

```
'SELECT `book_book`.`id`, ... `book_book`.`price`, `book_book`.`nump`, 
FROM `book_book` INNER JOIN `book_tagbook` ON (`book_book`.`id` =    
`book_tagbook`.`book_id`) WHERE `book_tagbook`.`tag_id` = 1  ORDER BY 
`book_book`.`nump` ASC LIMIT 11 OFFSET 1'
```

Do you have any idea on this? How could I fix it? Thanks.

---EDIT---

Checked the previous raw query in mysql as @bouke suggested:

```
SELECT `book_book`.`id`, `book_book`.`title`, ... `book_book`.`nump`, 
`book_book`.`raw_data` FROM `book_book` INNER JOIN `book_tagbook` ON 
(`book_book`.`id` = `book_tagbook`.`book_id`) WHERE `book_tagbook`.`tag_id` = 1  
ORDER BY `book_book`.`nump` ASC LIMIT 11 OFFSET 1;
11 rows in set (4 min 2.79 sec)
```

Then use explain to find out why:

```
+----+-------------+--------------+--------+---------------------------------------------+-----------------------+---------+-----------------------------+--------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table        | type   | possible_keys                               | key                   | key_len | ref                         | rows   | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+--------------+--------+---------------------------------------------+-----------------------+---------+-----------------------------+--------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | book_tagbook | ref    | book_tagbook_3747b463,book_tagbook_752eb95b | book_tagbook_3747b463 | 4       | const                       | 116394 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | book_book    | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                     | PRIMARY               | 4       | legend.book_tagbook.book_id |      1 |                                 |
+----+-------------+--------------+--------+---------------------------------------------+-----------------------+---------+-----------------------------+--------+---------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.10 sec)
```

And for the table book_book:

```
mysql> explain book_book;
+----------------+----------------+------+-----+-----------+----------------+
| Field          | Type           | Null | Key | Default   | Extra          |
+----------------+----------------+------+-----+-----------+----------------+
| id             | int(11)        | NO   | PRI | NULL      | auto_increment |
| title          | varchar(200)   | YES  |     | NULL      |                |
| href           | varchar(200)   | NO   | UNI | NULL      |                |
 ..... skip some part.............
| nump           | int(11)        | NO   | MUL | 0         |                |
| raw_data       | varchar(10000) | YES  |     | NULL      |                |
+----------------+----------------+------+-----+-----------+----------------+
24 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Try having an index on the field which you are trying to use in `order_by` clause

Comment: Already have done that. Didn't help. But db_index does help when using Book.objects.order_by ('-popular'). @AamirAdnan

Comment: There is a discrepancy between the code you posted (ordering by popular) and the RAW SQL snippet (ordering by nump). You would need to have a DB index on the field that you're using to sort, like @AamirAdnan commented.

Comment: @bouke I modify the nump field to popular manually in order to make it easier to read. But forget to modify the raw sql part (fixed now). It still didn't work. Do you think it might be the problem of mysql or django? mysql: Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.31, for debian-linux-gnu (i686) using readline 6.2

Comment: Did you try to run the SQL directly on MySQL, if that's also slow you'd factored Django out of the question. Try to do `EXPLAIN [your query]` to find out more about your query and identify why it's slow.

Comment: @bouke I ran the raw query in mysql, same timing as in django. I edited the question and added EXPLAIN output, do you have any ideas?

Comment: I'm guessing that the INNER JOIN might be your problem here; the explain shows a `using temporary; using filesort`, which might produce the performance problems.

Comment: So your options are: 1. figure out why MySQL gives a bad performance or 2. sort the list using Python.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39183/discussion-between-okidogi-and-bouke)

Comment: @okidogi  will suggest you to use [django-debug-toolbar](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar) to check what queries were executed and which query takes much time. I also know that having limit on query will drastically improves performance so try having that as well.